# JpaRepository deleteById method doesn't work inside an if statement where an exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa

I have a strange problem. I want to implement the feature where a user signs up and gets a verification token, which remains valid for some time, and the user can activate his account. If the token expires before the user activates his account, the user is deleted from the db and an exception is thrown. But, deleteById method of JpaRepository doesn't work when i put it inside an if statement before the exception. So i cannot delete the user. Here is my code:

```
 private void fetchUserAndEnable(String verificationToken){
        User user = userRepository.findByVerificationToken(verificationToken).orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotFoundException("User has not been found"));

        //check if signup token has expired or not
            if(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - user.getCreated().toEpochMilli() > 1500_0){
                System.out.println(user.getUserId());
                userRepository.deleteById(user.getUserId());
                throw new PortfolioException("The verification token has expired!");
            } 

        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

However this line before the exception gets executed:

```
 System.out.println(user.getUserId());
```

and this line - not:

```
 userRepository.deleteById(user.getUserId());
```

But, when i do not throw the exception inside the "if" statement, deleteById method works:

```
 private void fetchUserAndEnable(String verificationToken){
            User user = userRepository.findByVerificationToken(verificationToken).orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotFoundException("User has not been found"));
    
            //check if signup token has expired or not
                if(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - user.getCreated().toEpochMilli() < 1500_0){
                    System.out.println(user.getUserId());
                    userRepository.deleteById(user.getUserId());
                } else {
                    user.setEnabled(true);
                    userRepository.save(user);
             }
        }
```

Why does it happen? And what is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: How are you sure that it does not get executed? Do you get an error or something? Or do you simply check the database for changes?

Comment: First of all your logic doesn't convince me. Why `Exception`? One expects from  `fetchUserAndEnable()` method to fetch a user and enable if found. And show us where you are using `@Transactional`. But, the second way is the right way to go imo

Comment: @TheCoolDrop, yeah, i check the db to see whether it works or not

Comment: Aman, I had tried @Transactional annotation before i posted the question and it didn't work. I need an exception to be thrown to send it to an angular app, otherwise the app won't understand that smth went wrong. The solution offered by Piotr Podraza: "@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PortfolioException.class)" helped me, now it works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you run this code inside transaction that gets rolled back because of the `PortfolioException` you are throwing.

To get around that if you use `@Transactional` annotation, simply state that you do not expect the transaction to be rolled back on `PortfolioException` via `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PortfolioException.class)`. That way transaction is going to be commited regardless of the exception and user will be deleted.

Comment: No, i didn't use @Transactional annotation. I had tried it earlier but it didn't work and i dropped it. However i added your code: @Transactional(noRollbackFor = PortfolioException.class) and it started to work. Thank you! But could you explain why does this happen?

Comment: By default any `RuntimeException` thrown inside transaction span cause it to be rolled back - that means the changes you had made prior to the exception won't affect your database state. With `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = PortfolioException.class)` you instruct Spring to make an exception for `PortfolioException` so it does not casue the rollback like other `RuntimeException`s do.

Comment: Thanks, Piotr for your help! Now i know what to do if this scenario reoccurs